# Check UITextField while editing for different regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex, uitextfield

I would like to check my `passwordTextField` while editing. I have three different criteria:

1. at least 8 characteres
2. at least 1 upper and lowercase letter
3. at least 1 digit

I already have this function which I need afterwards for checking all three cases at once:

```
static func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool {

    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[A-Z]).(?=.*[0-9]).(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

But for now I need to check the different cases separately **while editing**  my `textField`.

I basically need 3 different regex checks inside some sort of `whileEditing` method I am stuck here...

Is there an easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UITextField` `EventListner` method, to check your conditions. You can also set the below in `Nibs` or `Storyboards`,

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This `passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)` returns a result of unknown predicate hit so you have to separate them to handle what you need e.x there may be 8 charaters but no digits between them

Comment: sorry I think I was not very clear in my question. I updated it. I know I need 3 different tests but how do I realize that and is there an easy function to check whileEditing?